# Get toDebugString from DecisionTreeClassifier in PySpark ML

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I trained a `DecisionTreeClassifier` model using a pipeline like this one:

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler, StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml.classification import DecisionTreeClassifier

cl = DecisionTreeClassifier(labelCol='target_idx', featuresCol='features')
pipe = Pipeline(stages=[target_index, assembler, cl])
model = pipe.fit(df_train)

# Prediction and model evaluation
predictions = model.transform(df_test)
```

where the stages are instances of `StringIndexer` and `VectorAssembler`. I can now evaluate the accuracy of the model, for example, with

```
mc_evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(
labelCol="target_idx", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="precision"    )

accuracy = mc_evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
print("Test Error = {}".format(1.0 - accuracy))
```

Great. Now I need to check the tree model structure. The docs point me to an attribute called `toDebugString`, but the ML `DecisionTreeClassifier` does not have this one - it seems to be an attribute only for the MLLib `DecisionTree` classifier. How can I get the tree structure from the model inside the pipeline from the ML version and plot it?

Comment: Issue open: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15092

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me in pyspark:

```
model.stages[2]._call_java('toDebugString')
```

Comment: This is a good workaround for now. The JIRA that I submitted started a few changes to handle these cases. You can follow the history here: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/12919/commits/91c293af911d173670fb71857a38601745322285